# The page cannot be displayed error Facebook

Tags: facebook

This is the FB Url I am trying to access. 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=694aa71aed60fb9d79aae04b81ff27c8&redirect_uri=http://localhost/TestConnect/Facebook.aspx&scope=email,user_about_me,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_education_hi

It says 
The page cannot be displayed
There are too many people accessing the Web site at this time.
It was working fine until last night
Even when I type it in the browser, it has no response. All it shows me is a green progress bar even after 20min

What should I do?
Thanks
SC

Comment: You're redirected to localhost. Did you remember to turn on your local web server when you started working on this today?

Comment: Hi, I did not turn off the local web server. I've been banging my head against this for a few nights now and hoping another set of eyes can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your URL :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize
?client_id=694aa71aed60fb9d79aae04b81ff27c8
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/TestConnect/Facebook.aspx
&scope=email,user_about_me,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_education_hi
```

When changing `redirect_uri` to `http://localhost` it works fine for me. So I guess it is your page `http://localhost/TestConnect/Facebook.aspx` that does not works fine.

The `redirect_uri` will be called with GET parameters, be sure to handle them correctly :

- If the user **allows** your app, he will be redirected to :

  ```
  http://localhost/TestConnect/Facebook.aspx?code=...
  ```

  and you will need to get a ask an access token to facebook with that code (the `code` parameter) by calling :

  ```
  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
     ?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
     &redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
     &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
     &code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
  ```
- If the user **doesn't allow** your app, he will be redirected to :

  ```
  http://localhost/TestConnect/Facebook.aspx
     ?error_reason=user_denied
     &error=access_denied
     &error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
  ```

  so you can detect that error by testing the get parameter `error`.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Hey Smitha, what was the problem then ? Did you managed to make it work ?